# MYSQL: Create procedure ERRORS with syntax on Insert

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, dml

So I'm trying to calculate total cost before insert into a database using a procedure. The entire idea is check if late payment is null then not null and if the value is 0.

So far I have this:

```
DELIMITER;;
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_transaction
    (IN accTransactionId INT(11), IN auctionId INT(11), IN chittyAccNo INT(11), IN `date` DATETIME, IN amount DOUBLE, IN description VARCHAR(50),
    IN transref VARCHAR(50), IN tranStat TINYINT, IN clearDate DATETIME, IN methodPaid DATETIME)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE latePayment int(11);
        DECLARE total AS DOUBLE;

        SELECT `LatePaymentFee`
        INTO `latePayment`
        FROM chittyusers
        WHERE ChittyAccNo = NEW.ChittyAccNo;

        CASE 
            WHEN latePayment IS NULL 
        THEN
            SET total = amount ;

            WHEN latePayment IS NOT NULL
        THEN
            SET total = amount + latePayment;
        ELSE
            SET total = amount;
        END;
        END CASE;

        INSERT INTO `chittytransactions` (`ChittyTransactionID`, `AuctionID`, `ChittyAccNo`, `Date`, `Amount`,
         `Description`, `TransRefence`, `TransStatus`, `ClearanceDate`, `PaymentMethod`)
        VALUES (accTransactionId, auctionId, chittyAccNo, `date`, amount, description, transref, tranStat, clearDate, methodPaid)

    END;;
DELIMiTER;
```

When I try to create this procedure I'm getting sql syntax error:

> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 5

Am I doing something wrong and what can be changed. just Started using these so I don't fully understand how they work yet.

Also If you need the database this is it:

```
    CREATE TABLE `chittytransactions` (
  `ChittyTransactionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `AuctionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ChittyAccNo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Amount` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `Description` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TransRefence` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Reference from actual Bank transaction',
  `TransStatus` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'If Transaction Pending or Cleared',
  `ClearanceDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `PaymentMethod` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0- Cash, 1- bank transfer, 2- personal credit etc'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
CREATE TABLE `chittyusers` (
  `ChittyAccNo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UserId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ChittyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LatePaymentFee` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thank You Any help would be great

Comment: Didn't you change the delimiter before exeuting this code like `delimiter | create procedure ... end |`?

Comment: No don't think I need to specify a delimiter when creating procedure?..

Comment: ok I just added that and I'm still getting syntax error on the other commands. can you please have a look and tell me what you think is wrong with the entire thing.

Comment: Use something like *MySQL Workbench*. It highlights errors and you can fix it yourself. I am pretty sure the answerer used it.

Comment: And don't forget a space between `delimiter` and the actual delimiter.

Comment: ok thanks but its saying that there a problem with my insert statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- a delimiter is needed
- "create or replace" doesn't seem to be accepted
- there is an additional "as" in the *total* variable declaration
- there is an additional "end" before "end case"
- there is a missing semicolon at the end of the last insert

This seems to be accepted:

```
drop procedure if exists add_transaction;
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE add_transaction
(IN accTransactionId INT(11), IN auctionId INT(11), IN chittyAccNo INT(11), IN `date` DATETIME, IN amount DOUBLE, IN description VARCHAR(50),
IN transref VARCHAR(50), IN tranStat TINYINT, IN clearDate DATETIME, IN methodPaid DATETIME)
BEGIN
    DECLARE latePayment int(11);
    DECLARE total DOUBLE;

    SELECT `LatePaymentFee`
    INTO `latePayment`
    FROM chittyusers
    WHERE ChittyAccNo = NEW.ChittyAccNo;

    CASE 
        WHEN latePayment IS NULL 
    THEN
        SET total = amount ;

        WHEN latePayment IS NOT NULL
    THEN
        SET total = amount + latePayment;
    ELSE
        SET total = amount;
    END CASE;

    INSERT INTO `chittytransactions` (`ChittyTransactionID`, `AuctionID`, `ChittyAccNo`, `Date`, `Amount`,
     `Description`, `TransRefence`, `TransStatus`, `ClearanceDate`, `PaymentMethod`)
    VALUES (accTransactionId, auctionId, chittyAccNo, `date`, amount, description, transref, tranStat, clearDate, methodPaid);

END;
$$
```

Comment: @juergen-d yes, I did use MySQL Workbench to verify and test this, it's indeed very helpful.

Comment: I should start using that. can i get it for macbook?

Comment: Thanks you very much Mr D :)